# How to call image URL from HTML instead of CSS?

Tags: html, css, less

I am make CMS for my company's website. We have a requirement. We need to design a header of a page. Image needs to be changeable from CMS. In order to achieve this I need to call the image from HTML instead of CSS.

Below is my code:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  &:before {
    content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#002f4b,#dc4225);
 opacity: .6; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

1. Need to call image URL from html
2. Don't know why code is not working in Stack Overflow, but is working in my [codepen here](https://codepen.io/alexcarpenter/pen/LveDx)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `style` attribute:

```
<div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline-styles for this.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg-img::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800')"></div>
```

Comment: The overlay is working on codepen, I assume it is something about SO

Comment: Because CodePen allows SCSS notation, but Stack Overflow expects the processed CSS. See my updated code, now it works.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tag for image :

```
<img src="superPower.jpg" alt="Super Power">
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle, i tried but its not working, i know the tag though

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".bg-img img").each(function(i, elem) {
    var img = $(elem);
    var div = $("<div></div>").css({
      background: "url(" + img.attr("src") + ")",
    });
    div.html(img.attr("alt"));
    div.addClass("replacedImage");
    img.replaceWith(div);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.replacedImage {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
}

.replacedImage:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);
  opacity: .6;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200x800" alt="">
</div>
```